# After Connect to wifi wait for response that password entered is correct and to show Connected?

Tags: java, android

i want to create a wifi scanning app that display users with available wifi near them in a listview and on clicking on listview it will open dialog in which wifi password is entered, so I want when user entered the password and clicked on the connect button. It will close the dialog and wificonfiguration object will be created and wifimanager will call reconnect ,At this point I want user to know that the password entered was correct and he has been connected 
display it with the prompt and if password entered is wrong display you entered wrong password/disconnected.

```
public class NextPage extends ListActivity {


//public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    WifiManager mainWifiObj;
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
    ListView list;
    String wifis[];

    EditText pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_next_page);

        list=getListView();
        mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        mainWifiObj.startScan();

        // listening to single list item on click
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // selected item
                String ssid = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                connectToWifi(ssid);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wifi SSID : "+ssid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        registerReceiver(wifiReciever,new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));

        super.onResume();
    }
    class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public  boolean connected = false;
        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
            wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
            for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
                wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
            }
            String filtered[] = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
            int counter = 0;
            for (String eachWifi : wifis) {
                String[] temp = eachWifi.split(",");

                filtered[counter] = temp[0]+temp[1]+temp[2]+temp[3];//.substring(5).trim();//
                //
                // +"\n" + temp[2].substring(12).trim()+"\n" +temp[3].substring(6).trim();//0->SSID, 2->Key Management 3-> Strength

                counter++;

            }
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_item,R.id.label, filtered));
            ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager) c
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = mgr
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

            connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();

        }
        public boolean isConnected(){
            return connected;
        }
    }

    private void finallyConnect(String networkPass, String networkSSID) {
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", networkSSID);
        wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", networkPass);

        // remember id
        int netId = mainWifiObj.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
        mainWifiObj.disconnect();
        mainWifiObj.enableNetwork(netId, true);
        mainWifiObj.reconnect();   //i want the code here that if wifi 
                                   //object connect then i will get a 
                                  //response so that i can display user 
                              //that he has got connected I am a begineer 

        //WifiInfo info=mainWifiObj.getConnectionInfo();
        //info.getHiddenSSID();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User:"+wifiReciever.isConnected(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        /*if(info.getDetailedStateOf(info.getSupplicantState())==NetworkInfo.DetailedState.FAILED){
            if(info.getSSID().equals(networkSSID)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"check: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not fouund",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }*/
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"check: "+k,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
      //  conf.SSID = "\"\"" + networkSSID + "\"\"";
      //  conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
       // mainWifiObj.addNetwork(conf);
    }

    private void connectToWifi(final String wifiSSID) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.connect);
        dialog.setTitle("Connect to Network");
        TextView textSSID = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textSSID1);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        pass = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textPassword);
        textSSID.setText(wifiSSID);

        // if button is clicked, connect to the network;
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String checkPassword = pass.getText().toString();
                finallyConnect(checkPassword, wifiSSID);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```